# How can I get row's index from a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, row, rank

I have a `Toplist` table and I want to get a user's rank. How can I get the row's index?

Unfortunately, I am getting all rows and checking in a for loop the user's ID, which has a significant impact on the performance of my application.

How could this performance impact be avoided?

Comment: A rank is not the same as a row-number. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

Comment: As Tim is 100% correct, i think in a "toplist" the row number becomes the rank?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use ROW.NUMBER

This is a example syntax for MySQL

```
SELECT  t1.toplistId, 
        @RankRow := @RankRow+ 1 AS Rank
FROM    toplist t1
JOIN    (SELECT @RankRow := 0) r;
```

This is a example syntax for MsSQL

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY YourColumn) AS Rank,TopListId
FROM TopList
```

Answer (score 12):

You may also do something like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS MyIndex
FROM TopList
```

Answer (score 5):

[ROW_NUMBER() MS SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186734.aspx)

Use in your code analytic functions